# Form authentication in Google Apps

Tags: google-app-engine, forms, authentication

I've been wondering if it's possible to build and application in Google AppEngine (GAE) and provide to users not only a login through the Google Accounts. I'd like to also offer my own authentication. Something like http://www.appdemostore.com/signin . This app is built on top of GAE and not only provides a Google Accounts method to authenticate its users. It has a form authentication and a form to create an account hosted by itself. So, my point is: How could i implement something similar. Is it possible authenticate through my own forms and user's accounts instead of only Google Accounts?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Your users will be much better served by offering them Google Account and/or OpenID options. Few users want to create yet another account.

Answer (score 1):

Ya you can, You should also manage sessions and store user entity on datestore on your own. 
If you are using python. You should have a look at [gaesessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions).Your model will look  something like

```
class Profile(db.Model):
    name=db.TextProperty()
    email=db.EmailProperty()
    contact=db.StringProperty()
    address = db.StringProperty()
    image=db.BlobProperty()
    passcode=db.StringProperty()#hash value
```

Comment: @blackjack. I am sure that its possible in both java and python. I have implemented myself in python.

Comment: Thanks Abdul, Actually i'm using java, however that's not the point. So, if i clearly understood, i could also handle the authentication and restrict access to some areas of my app. I'll try to do it using java in some similar way to gaesessions example. thanks again